# Slider binded to two different Textbox with different range

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, slider

I have a `Slider` in WPF and I want to bind the same slider to two different Values. But each of these values have different range. For example the first one represents time and changes between 0 to 1.5 second and the second value represent percentage that ranges from 0 to 100. Is it possible to bind the value of the `Slider` to both of them in a way that user can also type any value within the range and both slider and other value get updated. For example if the user put the time value to 1, the `Slider` should move and also the value of the percentage should be set to 66.66 %.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `MultiBinding` with custom `MultiValueConverter` probably?

Comment: The [`Slider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.110).aspx) has `Minimum` and `Maximum` dependency property, which you can bind too.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes but my `Maximum` and `Minimum` for two different values are different.

Comment: @ASh `MultiBinding` should be implemented for all three controls? (`Slider` + two `TextBox`)

Comment: @VegaBrothers, I think two-way binding on a slider alone should do

Answer (score 0):

Your solution might be something like this:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=wpfApp1:SampleViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="0-1.5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Value1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="0-100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Value2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <Slider Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Value2}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new SampleViewModel();
        }
    }

    public sealed class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _value1;
        private double _value2;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public double Value1
        {
            get { return _value1; }
            set
            {
                if (_value1 == value)
                    return;

                _value1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value1));
                _value2 = Math.Round(100 / 1.5 * value, 1);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value2));
            }
        }

        public double Value2
        {
            get { return _value2; }
            set
            {
                if (_value2 == value)
                    return;

                _value2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value2));
                _value1 = Math.Round(1.5 /100* value, 1);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value1));
            }
        }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

However its for a 'well-known' min/max values. If you need dynamic ones (you dont know min/max on compile time, and it would be the only right solution to avoid any hardcoded stuff) you need to do some math.
Also you can achieve the same result using multibinding, just pass min/max and values and do all the math inside.

Comment: I am calculating them at compile time. What I do right now (which I don't like) I binded the slider to one of the textbox, and then on Slider value change I update the other manually. I will try to see how your approach work and report back. Thanks.